# Rails 3 available_locales excluding gem translations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, internationalization

I have a Rails 3 app in which I'm using I18n.available_locales to display a list of available languages for user accounts. In my config/locales directory I only have en and nl yml files, however, I18n.available_locales returns a variety of other locale keys which I'm assuming are present due to translations being present in the gems that I'm using. Is there a common/standard way to get the method to only return the translations present in the app itself?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would suggest, you use this gem : [rails-i18n](https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n) , it provides basic translations for every languages, and then, restrict available locales with

```
config.i18n.available_locales = ['es-CO', :de]
```

Of course, rails-i18n is not mandatory here, you could simply define `available_locales` in your `config/application.rb` file

And as said in the comments, you should definitely accept some answers to improve your accept_rate

Comment: This does not work on Rails 4.2. It still returns the whole list.

Comment: @b1nary: I just tried in my rails 4.2 app and it worked. I added `config.i18n.available_locales = [:en]` in `config/application.rb` and then `I18n.available_locales` returns `[:en]` when I look at it in a `rails c`

Comment: do you have gems mounted with their own language files tho?

Comment: I'm not really sure I understand the question, but I don't think so. I also don't really see how this relates to the question. There might be a problem with one of the gems you're using, but this doesn't really change the fact that the suggested line of config should work to restrict what gets returned by `available_locales`